# Selenium Stale Element Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm making a bot to delete and recreate a Discord Channel again and again.

> Even if the elements are collected again after refreshing, the code is showing Stale Element Error

```py
def remake_channels(self):
        sleep(5)
        script = """
            document.querySelectorAll('a[aria-label="aa"')[0].click()
        """
        self.driver.execute_script(script)
        def delete_channel():
            channels = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'content-3at_AU')]")
            for channel in channels:
                text = channel.get_attribute('innerText')
                if text == 'new':
                    self.action.context_click(on_element = channel)
                    self.action.perform()
                    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Delete Channel')]").click()
                    sleep(1)
                    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Delete Channel')]").click()
                    print("Deleted The Channel")

        def make_channel():
            script = """
            document.querySelectorAll('div[class="contents-18-Yxp"]')[1].click()
            """
            self.driver.execute_script(script)
            sleep(1)
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@class, 'inputDefault-_djjkz input-cIJ7To')]").send_keys('new')
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Create Channel')]").click()
            print("Added The Channel!")
                
        delete_channel()
        make_channel()
```

Amy help is appreciated <3

Comment: your element references (channels) are becoming stale after your click(s)... (the DOM is updating and your references are no longer valid.)

Comment: I am getting my elements after updating the DOM, still, it's showing stale element error

Comment: use a webdriverwait or just a plain sleep... DOM is probably still updating when you check.   You can also functionize the get_elements call and catch the stale element reference... if caught DOM is still updating... recall function.

Comment: will definately try it